# What is the difference between the two different types of Mecanum wheels?

Tags: wheel

While looking at Mecanum wheels, I noticed that there are two different designs that are popular.

One type holds the rollers in between the wheels frame, and the other holds the rollers from the center.

Is there a significant advantage to using one over the other?

Comment: Do you have any pictures so we can see which ones you are talking about?

Answer (score 3):

The first type of Mecanum wheel has the rollers held at both ends.

[image: Metal Mecanum Wheel]

This type has a greater load capability, but they have a disadvantage. When they are traveling sideways and meet an inclined plane, the metal rim can collide with the plane.

The second type of Mecanum wheel has the rollers held in the middle
[image: Mecanum Wheel]

This has lower load capability, because the wheels are cantilevered. However, it is much better at dealing with obstacles and inclined planes.

[image: Mecanum Wheel Colision]